# PS+ 1gb online storage limit shared between consoles?

Tags: psn, playstation-plus

PS+ offers 1GB of online save storage.  Is this shared across consoles?  That is, if I own a PS3, PS4, and Vita, do I get 1GB per device?  Or 3GB total?

Comment: I think it might be linked to your profile, not your console

Answer (score 3):

Per the section on [Online Storage](https://support.us.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2293/kw/online%20storage):

> The maximum available storage capacity for one Sony Entertainment Network account is 1GB ...

You get 1GB to share across all your devices. Other sources on the PlayStation website are less obvious, such as the PS4 section, which states that the maximum storage is 1GB (but does not specify per account or per console).

If you have multiple PS+ accounts, you can specify which account to store to by logging into the associated offline profile. You can use multiple accounts per console, so long as you do not exceed 1GB or 1,000 save files per account.

Comment: can confirm. Just delete half of mine online ps3 saves and only freed 46MB of my total 932MB saves. The rest should be coming from ps4 and vita.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same question as my PS4 save data uploads keep failing. Noting that I have a PS3 and PS Vita as well.

The information on Sony support site and documentation is not to clear on this topic. Though an interesting point to raise is that PlayStation PLUS sign-up indicates 1GB per device.

You will see this on the PlayStation Store, when you navigate to PlayStation PLUS sign-up, scroll to the 2nd last page and the Cloud Storage image depicts a PS3, PS4 and PS Vita each with their own 1GB of cloud storage.